# Selenium Side Runner Hangs in Firefox but Works Fine in Chrome

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-side-runner

I'm encountering an issue with Selenium Side Runner when running .side files in Firefox. The test runs successfully in both Chrome and Firefox when executed, but it hangs indefinitely when using  Firefox.

**Problem:**
When I run the test in Firefox using Selenium Side Runner, the test completes but doesn't print any progress information to the console. Additionally, the process never terminates. If the test encounters an error, it goes into an infinite loop. This is problematic as I intend to automate these tests using Jenkins.

**Command for Chrome:**

`selenium-side-runner --debug --config-file chrome_config.yml test.side`

**Chrome Config File:**

```
capabilities:
  browserName: "chrome"
  goog:chromeOptions:
    args:
      - no-sandbox
      - disable-dev-shm-usage
      - nogpu
      - headless
      - window-size=1680,1050
      - user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

**Command for Firefox:**

`selenium-side-runner --debug --config-file firefox_config.yml test.side`

**Firefox Config File:**

```
capabilities:
  browserName: "firefox"
  moz:firefoxOptions:
    args:
      - "-headless"
    prefs:
      general.useragent.override: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0"
```

Has anyone encountered this issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve it?

I tried to pass arguments directly into the console.
I tried to use a single. side file for both browsers unsuccessfully.
I tried numerous formatting changes for the firefox .side file.